# Slicing a dataframe based on datatype

Tags: pandas, indexing

```
    Country       Energy         ESupply
1   Afghanistan   321000000      10 
2   Albania       102000000 35   100
3   Algeria       1959000000     51 
4   American      LLLLLL.....   ....        
5   Andorra       9000000        121
```

I'm trying to look for anomalies/data corruption in my dataframe but by looking for non-numerical values.

How do I use boolean indexing to do this?

df.where(df !=  (int or float))

I looked through the docs but didn't find anything I felt I could use.

EDIT:

Here is how the dataframe looks after using PirSquared's first solution.
Don't mind the extra columns. (The OP example was a condensed version).

```
    Country    Energy Supply    Energy Supply per Capita    % Renewable
1   Afghanistan 321000000           10                       78.6693
3   Algeria     1959000000          51                       .55101
4   American Samoa  .................................................   ... 0.641026
5   Andorra    9000000              121                       88.6957
6   Angola     642000000             27                       70.9091
9   Argentina  3378000000            79                       24.0645
10  Armenia     143000000            48                        28.2361
```

So it was able to pull out some corrupted entries like  row `4` but it also pulled out non-corrupted entries.

Comment: How about df_corrupted = df.loc[:,df.dtypes != np.number]?

Comment: I quickly tested it out. It seems to be printing out the who dataframe, so it doesn't work? I will recheck after eating lunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
expect_numeric_columns = ['Energy', 'ESupply']
```

***option 1***
using `apply` with a `str.isnumeric`

```
corrupted = df[
    df[expect_numeric_columns].apply(
        lambda c: ~c.astype(str).str.isnumeric()
    ).any(1)
]
print(corrupted)

    Country        Energy ESupply
2   Albania  102000000 35     100
4  American   LLLLLL.....    ....
```

***option 2***
using `pd.to_numeric`

```
corrupted = df[
    pd.to_numeric(
        df[expect_numeric_columns].stack(), errors='coerce'
    ).unstack().isnull().any(1)
]
print(corrupted)

    Country        Energy ESupply
2   Albania  102000000 35     100
4  American   LLLLLL.....    ....
```

Comment: This is some high_level stuff. Going to go test it out.

Comment: Hi PiR, I'm getting this error:
`TypeError: ("bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'", 'occurred at index Energy Supply')`  .   ` Energy Supply` is the name of one of my columns. 
I'm using the Jupyter notebook (~ looks funny in the notebook, so not sure if that's causing the error?)

Comment: Thanks. Will test out after lunch.

Comment: First option  seems to be slicing the dataframe, but it's slicing non-corrupted dataas well. I will update my OP to show the results.